# C# equivalent function of PHP's random_bytes

Tags: c#

Does any one know what is the equivalent function of PHP's `random_bytes` and `hex2dec` in C#.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you could use [NextBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.nextbytes?view=net-5.0) from Random and here is a example to convert hex to decimal:

```
int decValue = int.Parse(hexValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```